# How to use bilibot?

Tags: ros, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just got a bilibot in our lab and am completely blank what to do with it.  It is severely lack documentation.  Currently diving the web ocean to find info.  Hopeful to get some help or directions here.  I am new with Ubuntu, ROS, Create; I have been working on MS Visual C++, and started with OpenNI in it.

A few questions as starter:

1. What does the Demo button do?  It doesn't do anything when I press it.  Can the Bilibot work without monitor, keyboard, mouse (I assume it should be able to)?
2. What does the E-stop do?  I am guessing it is emergency stop, but 'what' does it stop?  Ok, my Bilibot hasn't move yet.
3. In the Ubuntu, it is a clean desktop and I need to figure out what to do next.  I was expecting an icon on the desktop to do some form of demo/examples -- read somewhere.
4. My Bilibot does not come with USB-SCI cable and Create charger dock (for auto homing).  Is that normal?

Many thanks for any kind guidance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12928/how-to-use-bilibot?/) by [owh](https://answers.ros.org/users/1754/owh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2012-02-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Why don't you ask there: http://www.bilibot.com/join?
This site is about ROS, not Bilibot.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1